# Validation Form Replicating

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form that when is submitted it checks if the user selected the field, and if didn't it gives a message to fill, but if i keep clicking the message keeps duplicating, triplicating and goes on... How can i make the message appear only one time? Here is the code

```
$( "#myform" ).submit(function( event ) {
  var met = $("#mySelect").val();
  if (met === "0"){

    $( ".msn" ).append( "Select a Field" );
    return false 
  }else{
    $( "#myform" ).submit();
    }

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the problem is on the appended label try this:

```
$( "#myform" ).submit(function( event ) {
  var met = $("#mySelect").val();

  if (met === "0"){
    // Clear .msn 
    $(".msn").empty();

    // Append label
    $( ".msn" ).append( "Select a field" );

    return false 
  }else{
      $( "#myform" ).submit();
    }

});
```

Check this **[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jys81d6p/4/)**.

Comment: I tried, but it happens the same situation at first, its allways appearing the same message and starts duplicating, triplicating...and goes on

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle?

Comment: Ok, I've included a new solution above

Answer (score 0):

Use [.one](http://api.jquery.com/one/) function

```
$( "#myform" ).one('submit', function( event ) {
  var met = $("#mySelect").val();
  if (met === "0"){

    $( ".msn" ).append( "Select a Field" );
    return false 
  }else{
    $( "#myform" ).submit();
    }
```

});

Comment: I tried, but when i try to click again in the submit button the forms submits when should be blocked